# .apk installed on Android but cannot be found anywhere!

Tags: android, eclipse, installation

I have developed two small applications for Android using Eclipse. Then i ran them both on the phone by right-clicking on the project and "run as android application",  and they were successfully tested. However, when i try to install their .apk files, one of them appears in the list, while the other does not appear. I checked the application manager and it shows that the application is saved. 
I tried to find it using the "search" in the phone, it can find all saved .apk except this one.

Pls do you have any idea where did i go wrong especially that it seems saved, and only this application does not appear in the phone although the application manager says it is installed.

Comment: Does it have an activity that listens to the launcher main intent?

Comment: uninstall and run it again, I've had this happen before

Comment: are they separate packages? do they both have main launcher intents setup? do they have different manifests?

Comment: i made a new project and copied the exact same code, and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Found out why this was happening. You need this in your AndroidManifest as a part of your main activity.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

My mistake was that I used `<action android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>` instead of `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>`. Without the `category.LAUNCHER`, you're not telling it to list the software in the application launcher, so it becomes invisible.

Comment: Saving lives when deadline comes.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to enable third party apps on your phone since it is not able to find the one you created.
(Applications >> Enable Unknown sources)

Also you may want to use an APK installer(search) App like App Installer to easily find your own APKs and install them.

And as always uninstall and give it another go, as mentioned above it has happened to everyone it seems.

Answer (score -3):

Your way of description is quiet messy. By phone do you mean the emulator? If it cannot find the .apk and it doesn't appear in the project folder, then clean the project (Project menu) or restart Eclipse. This usually solves the problem. Idk why this is happening so often.