# I Can install apk of my project but cant see it, why?

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I download my project.apk to my mobile, I install it, at the end it says (Done) and (Open), the (Open) is unhighlighted, I go to (Done). When I look for it to run it, I cant find it, when I go to settings >> Applications to uninstall it, I find it!
Why? :)

Comment: Does your project work fine on the emulator?

Comment: It stopped, it says "No compatible targets were found. Do you wish to add a new Android Virtual Device?"

Comment: Could be a duplicate of this [question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507428/apk-installed-on-android-but-cannot-be-found-anywhere

Answer (score 1):

In AndroidManifest.xml check if you have this inside the Activity which is your main activity:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

This is the piece of XML that informs which activity is considered the main activity in your android application. If this information is missing, no launcher will be set, which means no way to start your activity. That's why you don't see an icon of your application, neither can you launch it.

Comment: It gave me these... [2014-04-05 00:30:29 - Device] Error during Sync: timeout.
[2014-04-05 00:37:27 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2014-04-05 00:37:28 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
[2014-04-05 00:37:39 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:EOF
[2014-04-05 00:37:41 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
[2014-04-05 00:37:43 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 2
[2014-04-05 00:37:45 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 3

Comment: Ok, try this:
1) Clean your project
2) Remove it from the device
3) Unplug the device and plug it back in again
4) Restart your IDE and try again.

This problem sounds IDE/ADT related.

Comment: How do I "Remove it from the device" :)

Comment: Go to the device "Settings" app. Then choose "apps", pick the app you want to remove and uninstall it. This steps may change depending on the device

Comment: Are you talking about the Mobile? I've done that, that if your talking about this issue!

Comment: I am referring to the Sync Error

Comment: I think I did what you want, but .. http://oi58.tinypic.com/2j2jlzo.jpg and http://oi62.tinypic.com/2ue4ec2.jpg .. just in case http://oi61.tinypic.com/280mtro.jpg

Comment: Woa, there is your problem right there, on the last picture! http://oi61.tinypic.com/280mtro.jpg You have to declare your activities in the manifest, and that piece of code that I gave you should be inside one of those activities!

Comment: Tell me, what is your activity's name? And in which package is it placed in?

Comment: Your application tag should look a little like this:
http://i62.tinypic.com/20jigir.png

Comment: You mean activity_main.xml? Or main.java?

Comment: You are working on a class, right? That class is extending Activity, what is the name of the class?

Comment: ok, in the manifest the active name should be "com.dd.dgaga.main"  Oh, and by the way, you should really read about the Java / Android naming conventions. A class should always start with an uppercase character :)

Comment: Im a newbie :) I studied a little Java about 15 years ago, I didnt "see" Java sense then and I didnt take xml .. anyway, I changed it but still, how can I rename "main" to "Main"?

Comment: select the file in the left pane, click with the second mouse button and choose refactor->rename 
You should ALWAYS do this, as it renames any references to this class

Comment: I troubled you tf.alves .. I've changed it, still an error in Main.java and in Manifest with the same things, I renamed main.java to Main.java

Comment: No problem, could you please post an image of your manifest and Main.java code?

Comment: solve the error on the manifest first, then in your Main.java you should be importing com.dd.dgaga.R instead of android.R

Comment: I tried manifest in activity android:name= .. the error didnt go away!

Comment: I'd suggest you start over with a fresh project. It's not that hard to fix the problems you have, but we would spend the whole day around here just to get it going. You should really read a bit more and following some tutorials. The problems you are having are simple and elemental ones, that's why you should look a bit more into tutorials.

Comment: Imade a new one but a same or different problem, I posted it else where but.. I create a New Application Project, and choose Android 2.2 for Minimum Required SDK and Target SDK, for Compile With; API8, it tells me I can't Create Activity, so I accept. I create package and a class named MainActivity.java in src and activity_main.xml in layout, before all that, I create http://i.stack.imgur.com/BZlOa.png When I write everything correctly (I think) and Run as > Android Application it stops and I get this message in the console: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UtpHE.png http://oi62.tinypic.com/esp1rs.jpg